# How to command PHP to open MS Word on PC and open the MS Word file on it

Tags: php

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to make a little script on PHP through which when the user clicks on "View File", the MS Word application on the client's computer should open automatically if it exists, and display/open the document file that is on the server. I have tried using exec() and COM but they both don't seem to work properly. Here is the code I'm using to open MS Word.

```
com_load_typelib('Word.Application');
$word = new COM("word.application");
$docName='C:/xampp/htdocs/phpword/helloWorld.docx';
$word->Documents->Open($docName);
```

This is the code I'm using to open the file.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'COM' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpword\word.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpword\word.php on line 16

This is the error I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control the client's computer from your PHP server. `exec()` for example will execute a program on your PHP server, but you cannot run programs, open files etc on the client's computer. That is a hacker's job :)

Comment: How does the "Mail" application do that then? It automatically opens MS Word if the file is in .doc or .docx format

Comment: What you have described in your comment is a simple download process. When you open an attachment from your email, the browser will attempt to download it. Depending on the browser and it's settings, you can have different behavior. My firefox for example, when I download a file, it displays a popup of what I want to do: open the file or save the file. Opera for example it saves the file automatically on my desktop without asking. The effect is dependent on the client's browser settings.